# Book where 'others' are clones from the future sent back to gain ability to reproduce

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

During the story, strange things keep happening like alien kidnappings or other events. The nature of the 'others' isn't revealed until towards the end.

I remember a question by a protagonist to the others near the end of the book goes like, "Is there intelligent life out there?" To which the response was, "Not any more, we won."

The 'Time/Spaceship' was  called a 'pa' after the traditional Maori settlement, and it is implied (or maybe even stated) that a calamity was going to affect the earth and that the protagonists should head to New Zealand, thus perpetuating the timeline.

Comment: Not the story you are after, but the Philip K Dick short story `A World of Talent` also features 'others' who come from the future.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is *Nighteyes*, by Garfield Reeves-Stevens.  ISBN 978-0553285031.

It involved alien abductions related to certain families.

Spoilers:

> The 'aliens' were human time-travelers from the far future.  An
>  unspecified calamity (involving massive auroras) had wiped out most
>   of the human population, with only 300 people in the New Zealand
>  area having survived to repopulate.
>  In the future, humanity won a war against the aliens; this is the 
>  reason for the quote about there being 'none anymore'.
>  The humanoids in the story consisted of several types (drones, controllers, 
>  connections, slights, engineers, soldiers) who were the genetically 
>  altered human army that won the war, but they had no reproductive ability and
>  greatly reduced emotional capacity. That is why the future humans were 
>  so disciplined and militaristic. They had mastered some forms of unknown 
>  physics totally different from what is known today, (using the 
>  fundamental principals "transference" and "placement").
>  The reason they were going back in time to was to gather genetic 
>  material, motherly caretakers, and historical artifacts from the world
>  immediately before the cataclysm, whose absence wouldn't be missed 
>  (no paradoxes) as it would all have been destroyed in the cataclysm
>  anyway.  It's more complicated than that, but that's a good enough
>  summary.